# Embedding youtube player with playlist view

Tags: html, css, wordpress, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to embed a Youtube player with the playlist videos on the side like on the main Youtube website, like so: 
[image: playlist]

I have the following on my webpage:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=RDEMI0V0e34vA6znf4KLMCIbbQ" width="500" height="300" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" modestbranding="1"></iframe>
```

However this displays only the Youtube video with an icon in the player to see the rest of the videos in the playlist. I want the list to always show when there is space available on the page.

[image: playlist]

Is this possible with the Youtube player? If not, are there alternative video players that would allow me to do this. If relevant, my webpage is on WordPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It´s not possible with the Youtube player, but there are a few wordpress plugins you could use to get a preview of the other playlist videos. [Video Gallery](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yotuwp-easy-youtube-embed/) for example, is a simple and quite good one.